# Circular edges on a plane with example

Tags: mesh

How can I make the outer edges of my plane a circle like in image 2?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: final]

You can use **LoopTools** add-on, turn it on it the **User Preferences**:

[image: loop]

After it select outer rim and press <kbd>W</kbd> > **LoopTools** > **Circle**.